# How to keep users of my firebase app logged in despite the 1 hour token expiration time

Tags: firebase, authentication, token

I am new to firebase.

I don't understand **how I can keep the users of my firebase app logged in when the max expiration time of an auth token in 1 hour**.

I could use a function that uses the refresh token every hour but **what do I do if the users phone isn't charged?**

Thank you very much for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Firebase user's **access token** (or ID token) has a lifetime of an hour. After signing in the user, Firebase issues a **refresh token** that is used to get new access tokens if that refresh token is still valid and hasn't been revoked. If you are using the Firebase Client SDKs, they will handle getting new ID tokens as needed for you. Refer to the [ID tokens documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens) for more information.

An ID token essentially states "within the last hour, I have confirmed that I am this user".

If you are making use of [Custom Authentication tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens) from an Admin SDK, the token you give out to the caller also expires in an hour, but should be exchanged for a refresh token before it expires. Like described above, this new refresh token is used to request new ID tokens as they expire.

Comment: Thank you. Ah I see. The refresh token is valid for 200 days. I somehow assumed it also lasts only an hour.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase uses multiple token types to manage the authentication state of the user. The shortest lived of these (known as the ID token) expires an hour after it was created, but all Firebase SDKs actually automatically refresh that ID token before it expires.

This is handled for you behind the scenes, so in practice you shouldn't have to worry about token expiration - and your code can just [get the currently signed in user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user) everywhere it needs.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue that the token got expired every hour and the users had to login again mandatory.
The reason was that I apparently had modified something in the API page on Google console after adding Google Maps API.
The solution was for me to start a new firebase project and migrate the database to the new project. The issue was then solved.
This is a workable solution with small projects and limited users but I am sharing it for those who are interested.